# How can I edit an anchor tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, anchor

I want to create anchor tags that jump to which ever section of a page based on where the user clicks.

I have a few buttons: Web, Print, Logo and I've managed to use:

```
$(".project a").each(function() {
    var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(this).attr("href", _href + '#web');
});
```

What I need to do is remove the "http://mysite.com/#web" when I click another button like `#print`
Because right now it stacks ex "http://mysite.com/#web#print"

Comment: Why do you use javascript for this? Can't you just do <a href="#web">Web</a> <a href="#print">Print</a>, or am I missing something?

Comment: Normally I would for sure. I need javascript because I use a dynamic sorting portfolio as seen here http://idea-catalyst.com/our-work/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".project a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace(/#.*?$/,'#web');
});
```